# Reading audio file from socket inputstream in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, javascript, sockets, windows-phone

I'm trying to allow my computer to send music files to my app (Windows Phone 8). I use a socket to show a html file on my computer where I can select a file and upload it:

```
Upload music file:<br />
<input type="file" id="musicfile"/><br />
<input type="button" onclick="sendFile()" value="send"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function sendFile () {
    // get file
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('musicfile');
    var files = fileInput.files;

    // make request
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // response
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        alert("uploaded file");
      }
    }

    // send data
    xmlhttp.open("POST","upload",true);
    xmlhttp.send(files[0]);
  }
</script>
```

I read the filedata like so:

```
// handle request
private async void HandleRequest(StreamSocket socket)
{
    //Initialize IO classes
    DataReader reader = new DataReader(socket.InputStream);
    reader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;

    // read request
    var stringHeader = await reader.LoadAsync(4);
    if (stringHeader == 0)
    {
        // disconnected
        return;
    }

    // get length
    int length = reader.ReadInt32();

    // initiate data
    byte[] data = new byte[length];

    // load and read data
    uint bytes = await reader.LoadAsync((uint)length);
    reader.ReadBytes(data);
}
```

I get a OutOfMemoryException when trying to create byte[] data. Not suprising as length = 1215263604.

I wonder how it could be that large, the music file is 7.68MB.
The content type of the request is "audio/mp3".

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Content-Length header to get the size in the wp app? If it's returning an incorrect value, then make changes in the server so that the header value is available.

The OutOfMemoryException error will not arise then.